# php get url from url by get method

Tags: php, post, parameters, get

i have php page with get 2 parameters $link and $text
i want get $link parameter with all parameters inside it example

test.php?link=www.google.com?test=test&test2=test2&text=testtext

i want get link = 'www.google.com?test=test&test2=test2'
and get text = testtext

i use this php script

```
<?php

      $text = $_GET['text']; 
      $link = $_GET['link'];

      echo  $text;
      echo  $link;

?>

output

testtext
www.google.com?test=test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encode your parameters before using it on GET.

```
echo '<a href="test.php?link=' . urlencode('www.google.com?test=test&test2=test2') . '&text=' . urlencode('testtext') . '">test</a>';
```

In that way, there is no conflicts between google vars and yours.

See [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a URL as a parameter, you must escape it. Otherwise the parameters will appear as `$_GET` parameters inside your script.

You have to generate your link using `urlencode()`:

```
$link = "test.php?link=".urlencode("www.google.com?test=test&test2=test2")."&text=" . urlencode("testtext");
```

Also use quotation marks when using strings:

```
$text = $_GET['text']; 
$link = $_GET['link'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link_mod = str_replace("?", "&", $_GET['link']);
$array = explode("&", $link_mod);
unset($array[0]); #get rid of www.google.com segment
$segments = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
   $line_array = explode('=', $line);
   $key = $line_array[0];
   $value = $line_array[1];
   $segments[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($segments);
```